# How to detect left and right direction of a Bluetooth RC car (with Arduino) in Android Java and Arduino?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, arduino

I have seen code using an accelometer sensor, and there are no left or right buttons on the UI of the Android but the [RC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-controlled_model) car can still turn left or right by tilting the Android to the desired direction. Is it possible to do so using buttons?

I've searched online and found this example;

```
public void leftClick(View v) {
    mInstructionList.add(new Instruction(InstructionCommand.LEFT));
    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void rightClick(View v) {
    mInstructionList.add(new Instruction(InstructionCommand.RIGHT));
    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void forwardClick(View v) {
    mInstructionList.add(new Instruction(InstructionCommand.FORWARD));
    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void reverseClick(View v) {
    mInstructionList.add(new Instruction(InstructionCommand.REVERSE));
    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void stopClick(View v) {
    mInstructionList.add(new Instruction(InstructionCommand.STOP));
    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Is this correct? And how can the Arduino recognise the button click from Android?